# How to force 'http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js' to be loaded over https with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm getting this error in my inspector console now that I have Google Analytics running on it:

```
[blocked] The page at '...' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

I've searched hi and low for an answer and no one seems to be having this problem. I followed all the right instructions and don't seem to be having the same problems on other https sites that I'm monitoring with this same code. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Have you tried, you know, loading the script over HTTPS?

Comment: //crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js

Comment: How would I do that? Google Analytics says to just copy their snippet into your head tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try using https:

https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js

Instead of

http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js

Comment: This worked, and it turned out to be a secondary issue not related to my Google Analytics. Thanks!